# Getting Connection reset by peer while debugging django app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am debugging django app running inside docker container on my laptop. I attached vscode to the docker container and started the django app in debug mode. I have built a rest endpoint and put breakpoint on the first line in the REST endpoint. Now, I accessed that rest end point from postman REST client. It hit the breakpoint. Then, I stepped through the whole rest end point. It returned a desired JSON response, which I obtained in postman window. So the rest endpoint point seem to work fine, following the desired steps and returning the desired response. However after I receive the response in the postman window, a few seconds, vscode prints following in the same terminal window in which debugging is running:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.0.5.4', 52994)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Above stack trace does not list any file in my django app codebase, but only python library files. Also it does not show any error while stepping through the rest endpoint code. Whats going wrong here?

PS: Earlier till yesterday this REST endpoint was working just fine without printing above error. Also I guess, in some debug sessions (that is if I change some code and restart debugging) this error does not occur.